# Simple C++ program starts in multiple instances, task manager can't shut it down

Tags: c++, csv, console-application, ifstream

I'm trying to write a simple code to do some statistical calculations on a table of data stored in a .csv file. Unfortunately, the first few lines of my code doesn't work. When I compile and run it, it just shows a black cmd console, and when I open the task manager, I can see 3 instances of it running, and only one of them can be shut down. I use Code::Blocks IDE with GNU:GCC compiler on Windows 7. My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){ 

int length = 0;
float expmin;
float expmax;
float step;
int t;

ifstream source("D:\\statistic\\source.csv");

if (source.is_open()){

   cout<<"open"<<'\n';
   source.close();

}else cout<<"not open";
return 0;}
```

The unused variables are for later parts of the program. My other file input/output programs worked just fine. What's the deal with this, can you help me out?

Comment: Huh? You are immediately close source if it was opened? _`if (source.is_open()){ /* ...*/  source.close();
 }`_

Comment: Do you use Avast anti-virus?

Comment: The original code had a bunch of lines before `source.close();` but I wanted to simplify the problem. I do use avast, but it didn't cause a problem with my other projects. I think it's code::blocks causing the problem. I tried compiling the basic "Hello world!" console app and it did the same thing.

Comment: @David based on lot of other questions here on SO the Avast is your culprit. Disable it and run your program.

Comment: Disable Avast and try again.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I noticed there was something weird with my Avast, so I reinstalled it, and Code:Blocks too. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on my experience your program don't have the right to access that's path without admin privileges so here is the solutions that I can help with :

=> Close code-blocks >> right click on it's icon in the desktop >> Run as administrator >> execute your program again

And if the problem still exist then close your antivirus and do the same thing and if the problem still exist I think you should reinstall code-blocks or find another compiler :) :)

**UPDATE**

if nothing works then I think you should try your program line by line *i mean try to show message after every instruction to know where the error exactly
EXP:

```
instruction1();
showmessage("Instruction 1 is done");
instruction2();
showmessage("Instruction 2 is done");
instruction3();
showmessage("Instruction 3 is done");
  // Something like that :) :)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Running as an administrator didn't help. I will try reinstalling it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. After trying out different codes and realizing that all of them fail the same way, I reinstalled Code:Blocks and Avast. This solved the problem.